# Error 1004 AutoFill

Tags: excel, vba, range, runtime-error

The error is being thrown on the line

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("AJ2:AM2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AJ2:AM" & localLastRow)
```

It was previously cooperating, but after I corrected another error it seems that it doesn't want to play nice anymore. The source is contained within the destination. I am just not sure where the problem is coming from.

Any help would be very appreciated.
I have posted the entire macro below. It will eventually be one that is called into a main macro.

```
Sub FormulaUpdate()
'
' FormulaUpdate Macro
' Updates Columns AJ through AS
'
Dim localLastRow As Long
Dim sourceLastRow As Long
Dim wbName As String
Dim wbPath As String
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'sets strings from user's selection of Item Branch Report
wbPath = GetFile("Select Item Branch Report to be Used")
wbName = GetFilenameFromPath(wbPath)

Workbooks.Open(wbPath, ReadOnly:=True).Activate

'sets workseets to be referenced
Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")

'counts rows in selected item branch report for use elsewhere in macro
sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'range for use in vlookup formula, for both system leadtime and order min columns
Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("B1:BG" & sourceLastRow)

'Counts rows in this workbook for use elswhere in macro
localLastRow = thisSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'uses formulas in cells to autofill the data
thisSheet.Range("AJ2:AM2").AutoFill Destination:=thisSheet.Range("AJ2:AM" & localLastRow)


'loops through each row of both the system lead time, and the order min column, and sets the value from item branch report
For i = 2 To localLastRow

thisSheet.Range("AN" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(thisSheet.Range("C" & i), sourceRange, 53, False)
thisSheet.Range("AP" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(thisSheet.Range("C" & i), sourceRange, 58, False)
Application.StatusBar = "Referencing IBR: " & i & " of " & localLastRow & ": " & Format(i / localLastRow, "0%")

Next i

'uses formulas in cells to autofill the data
thisSheet.Range("AO2").AutoFill Destination:=thisSheet.Range("AO2:AO" & localLastRow)
thisSheet.Range("AQ2:AS2").AutoFill Destination:=thisSheet.Range("AQ2:AS" & localLastRow)

Workbooks(wbName).Close (False)
```

Comment: just make sure `localLastRow` is a valid number `> 2`

Comment: It is returning 5091 so that shouldn't be the source of error

Comment: but are you sure it's > 2? that would most likely cause the 1004 which is in the title of your question...

Comment: I added in a stop, and checked the value value before the formula is run, so I am pretty sure.

Comment: Maybe try fully qualifying your `Range`

Comment: Actually I just managed to fix it, by activating ThisWorkbook before hand. I'm fairly sure that a fully qualified range would have done the trick as well! Thank you.

Now to make the VLookUp work how it ought to...

Comment: Activating the sheet is not the appropriate solution. While it will "work", it's not a best practice.

Comment: @DavidZemens I edited my original post and replaced the code with my current version of the macro. I would love feedback if either of you would be willing. It all functions now, but I'm sure there's room for improvements.

Comment: @mehow ^ I would love any feedback as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mention above that is the *wrong* solution. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for background on why relying on `Select` and `Activate` methods is usually problematic, and should be avoided at all times. You have already encountered one frustrating problem -- which is that you need to keep track of which sheet is "active" and constantly update the code to have the appropriate sheet "active".  This makes for sloppy code that is difficult to navigate, and more expensive to execute.

The appropriate solution would be to fully qualify your range, for example:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("AJ2:AM2").AutoFill Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("AJ2:AM" & localLastRow)
```

**Why?**

Because, as you observe, an unqualified range *always* refers to the `ActiveSheet`.  One solution (the wrong one) is to continuously make the right sheet `Active`.  The right solution is to fully qualify your ranges, especially when working across multiple workbooks or worksheets.

Comment: I found that post you linked to be quite helpful. I was pretty much in the same boat as the guy who asked the question. Thank You! In my case here is it worth explicitly referring to the second workbook which is opened, as opposed to activating it and referencing that way? Or, is it the case that since there are only two workbooks here, referencing the opened workbook using ActiveWorkbook is tantamount to using a variable to reference?

Comment: IMO it would be a best practice to always use a variable to represent the workbook, rather than the `ActiveWorkbook` keyword.

Comment: ++ @DavidZemens also worth mentioning that `sourceLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` should also be fully qualified

Comment: @mehow good catch (although that method is less likely to raise an error)

Comment: @DavidZemens actually yeah you're right but when it's definitely a good practice specially when working with multiple instances of workbooks

Comment: definitely. the lastrow will likely vary between worksheets :) @mehow